# MVVMCross Fragment and dynamically setting event commands

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a MvxFragment that is bound to a view model that has two ICommand properties defined. This fragment contains an MvxListView and can be part of different activities/layouts dependant on the device size/orientation.

What I want to know is how to specify the ItemClick event command of the MvxBind property of the MvxListView dynamically or is there a better way to handle this use case? Should I use a separate fragment?

A similar use case to the one I am trying to achieve is within the Overview section of this [Xamarin Dev Guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/fragments_walkthrough/)

**View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <MvxListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Courses; ItemClick Comamnd1"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/coursetemplate" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**ViewModel (Simpified)**

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private MvxCommand<MyMessage> messageCommand;

    public MyViewModel (IMvxMessenger messenger, IHttpClientBuilderService httpClientBuilder)
    {
        this.httpClientBuilder = httpClientBuilder;
        this.messenger = messenger; 
    }

    public ICommand Comamnd1 {
        get { return new MvxCommand<Course> ((c) => ShowViewModel<MyOtherViewModel>(c)); }
    }

    public ICommand Command2 {
        get 
        { 
            messageCommand = messageCommand ?? new MvxCommand<MyMessage>(c => 
                {
                    var message = new MyMessage(this, c);
                    messenger.Publish(message);                     
                }); 
            return selectedCourse;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you can do this my overriding the [OnActivityCreated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) event for the fragment as below.

```
    public override void OnActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);

        MvxListView list = Activity.FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.[theID]);

        if (Activity.FindViewById<View>(Resource.Id.[fragmentID]) != null)
            list.ItemClick = ((MyViewModel)ViewModel).Command1;
        else
            list.ItemClick = ((MyViewModel)ViewModel).Command2;
    }
```

You can pull out the list by using the [Activity.FindViewById](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) function and then set the appropraite `ICommand` or `IMvxCommand` from the ViewModel via the `list.ItemClick` event